# Not getting anything in PHP $_SESSIONS

Tags: php

I've been trying to add a user login system to my site and have the following login page that seems to work fine (in so far as it checks username and password, passes the user through):

**index.php**

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
            <table width="510" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Login Form</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Address:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspa"2"><?php if(isset($_GET['f'])){echo("<h2>Login Failed</h2>");} ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    include 'includes/db_connect.php';
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

    $query = "SELECT password, salt FROM member WHERE email = :email";

    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $result->execute();

    $number_of_rows = $result->rowCount();

    if($number_of_rows == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
    {
        header('Location: index.php?f=1');
    }

    $userData = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );

    if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
    {
        header('Location: index.php?f=1');
    }else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('Location: results.php');
    }
?>
```

results.php

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Results</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    <?php
        //are you logged in?
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
            $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        }
        if(empty($email)){
            echo "You're not an authorized user. Please <a href='./index.php'>login</a>.<br />";
            exit();
        }
//rest of website
```

However, I always get the "You're not an authorized user..." error, I've tried putting a `var_dump()` and `var_export()` for `$_SESSION` but get **NULL** and `print_r` produces nothing, as does echo `$_SESSION['email']` which would suggest my `$_SESSION` global is empty, I have `session_start();` at the start of both login.php and results.php so the session should be there and continue.

I have things like WordPress installed on the same server so pretty sure things like `$_SESSION` works on the host and PHP is 7.2 so should be up to snuff too.

What dumb mistake am I overlooking?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions, it handles everything with cookies.

Comment: Have you checked whether the data is set to the session? Maybe the redirect to `index.php?f=1` is triggered?

Comment: add session_start(); at the beginning of the code.

Comment: remove the session_start(); from the results.php
could be starting it all over again!.. and so its blank!...

Comment: @Marty that's wrong.

Comment: @peter - that's amazing. I never knew....

Comment: yea would I should have said is check for the session, 
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

Comment: you can also use sessions in wordpress, just add the 
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
to your themeName/functions.php file

Comment: @Marty it doesn't matter -- if there is a session process then duplicate calls to `session_start()` ***resume*** the session.

Comment: @Sam you should ***NOT*** be using a salt on your password generation. You should be letting your system auto generate reliable salts itself. You should explore the `password_hash` PHP functions.

Comment: Thanks @Martin - I grabbed this from a free source code site and was attempting to patch it into my pages, will look into!

Comment: Hey, just to say thanks @Martin, I looked up `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php` and `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php` that made it real easy to implement into the above code and it's all working and much happier with it being more secure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `results.php`, you should have the `session_start()` at the top of your code before any HTML output.

```php
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
... rest of code
```

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

If you have error_reporting set to show E_WARNING, you should see the warning "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent..."